# Where variable between 2 column dates

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to do a MySQL select transaction however I am having difficulty getting it to do exactly what I want. I am trying to select all rows in which a set variable (@cdate) is between the dates (or is one of the 2 dates) listed in 2 columns (begindate and endingdate) - I have tried multiple attempts to do this however my table keeps returning 0 rows with everything I attempt.

resources table:

```
RID | begindate  | endingdate 
 1  | 2014-05-16 | 2014-05-17
 2  | 2014-05-15 | 2014-05-17
 3  | 2014-05-14 | 2014-05-15
 4  | 2014-05-17 | 2014-05-19
```

so in this scenario we are attempting to select * where "2014-05-16" either is a listed date or between the 2 listed dates which would ideally return RID: 1 and 2

I was thinking

```
SELECT        *
FROM            resources
WHERE        (begindate <= @cdate) AND (endingdate >= @cdate)
```

@cdate = "2014-05-16" in this case

but this did not work

Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: Your query should work.  Can you show the definition of the table and `@cdate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM resources
WHERE　@cdate　BETWEEN begindate AND endingdate
```

Comment: will between also include the date of begindate and endingdate?

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you selecting something between values the best option is `BETWEEN` Keyword. So the query must be like this

```
SELECT * FROM resources WHERE　@cdate　BETWEEN begindate AND endingdate
```